# where's the jar file in apache commons math 3.3.2?

Tags: jar, apache-commons

Just downloaded apache commons math 3.3.2 zip (source as opposed to binary) and extracted it. I want to add the jar to classpath in eclipse, but I can't find any file that looks right- only jar is called test. maybe that's it but I was expecting something more like math.commons.3.3.2.jar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the jar needed is in the binary (rather than source) download

Comment: Thanks! I found your answer in a google search. I downloaded the src rather than the binary as well. This worked!

Answer (score 2):

In eclipse, right click your project in the explorer. Click properties, and in the left column click "Javadoc location". Enter the URL "http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/" then it should add all the packages & jars to your project, allowing you to import and reference them with

```
org.apache.commons.math.(whichever package you would like);
```

Comment: I did that: it says 'the import org.apache cannot be resolved' and gines 7 quick fixes, one of which is to create the class SplineInterpolator in package org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.interpolation

Comment: In the project explorer, when you go to the referenced libraries, are the jars there?

Comment: I don't think so- how do I go to the referenced libaries?

Comment: When you open your project on the left column, under where it says jre(1.7) or whichever you are using, it should have a referenced libraries. When you open this, you should see apache packages.

Comment: So, when you right click the root folder of your project, and go to javadoc location it says "http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/"?

Comment: Try adding another slash at the end. I don't have eclipse with me at the moment, but when you press apply it should show up as a referenced librarym

Comment: however, it seems I've found an alternative solution: I think the jar I'm after is in the binary (rather than source) download. Your method looked good though- I'd like to know why it didn't work

Comment: tried adding another slash- no change- the javadoc location was already commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/ actually- it just removed the last slash in my earlier comment because i put http:// before the URL

Comment: You could try adding external source from the resources tab, and add your zip there, but you will have to manually download updates as they come.

Comment: I tried that- no joy, but i think I've got an answer now, as i said above- yes, the binary download contains the jar I needed

Comment: Alright, sorry I couldn't help. Glad you found a solution, good luck to you in your travels through eclipse! :)